# Android TimePicker - How to change to AM/PM when the time gets past 12 in 12h mode?

Tags: android, view, android-widget, timepicker, android-view

Is there a way to change the time from AM to PM(and vice versa) when the user clicks the '+' or '-' buttons of a TimePicker View, and the time gets past 12?

I'll give an example - If the time now is 11 AM, and the user clicks the '+' button of the TimePicker, the time changes to 12 AM(where it should change to 12 PM).

Is there a way of doing that? Why isn't the TimePicker doing it anyway?

I'm getting a lot of angry responses from my users because of this issue.

Any help will do,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a listener, keep track of the current time and then in the [`onTimeChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener.html#onTimeChanged%28android.widget.TimePicker,%20int,%20int%29) method you could detect the roll over and change the AM/PM settings yourself.

Comment: How can I change the AM/PM myself? And if I'd do that, wouldn't it call the onTimeChanged() method over and over again in an endless loop?

Comment: You should be able to just use `setCurrentHour` to move it forward. And I'm not sure, but I don't believe it will trigger the listener.

Comment: It does, I've just checked. I guess I can work out something, but it would be an ugly work-around.

Comment: Odd. Alright, I guess you could set the variable you're using to track the time to the final value BEFORE calling `setCurrentHour`, and then just ignore the callback if the new time isn't different from your variable. A bit of a hack, but the control isn't really designed to work the way you want it to, so some hackery is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `setIs24HourView(Boolean is24HourView)` method? It will remove AM/PM but at least the times will be in 24h mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would prefer to give the users the option to choose between 12h and 24h modes(most of the people are used to the 12h mode).

Comment: I can't see a method for changing AM/PM unfortunately, so I can't imagine how you could achieve this without a custom time picker.

EDIT: I think your only choice to get exactly what you are requesting is to make a custom timepicker, unfortunately.